# What does this sentence below mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, british-english

I have a problem to which I haven't been able to find a solution for hours. Recently, I have been reading Pygmalion by George Bernard Shaw, and there is a sequel after the story ends. In that sequel, Shaw wrote such a sentence,

> "To her amazement she found that some "quite nice" people were saturated with Wells, and that this accessibility to ideas was the secret of their niceness."

I can't understand what "be saturated with" and "accesibilty to ideas" mean. I have done some search on these 2 on Google but haven't been able find any satisfying answer. Please clarify me; I'd be so much grateful for you. Thanks.

Comment: I think context is needed to understand it. In general"be saturated with" means full of.

Comment: The source is [here](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/literature/p/pygmalion/summary-and-analysis/sequel/sequel-3).

Comment: I agree with Ronald Sole. By the way, we have been told (on the previous page) that Clara "discovered that her conversational qualifications were expected to include a grounding in the novels of Mr. H.G. Wells." And that she borrowed them and "swallowed them all within two months" and that "the result was a conversion of a kind quite common today." People at the time were evidently greatly affected by Wells's radical,  socialist and forward-looking ideas.

Comment: Yes makes sense. Yes I too agree with Ronald's answer.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - despite Wells' short stature and squeaky voice he was, famously, an enormous success with women. One of his ex-lovers said he 'smelt of honey'.

Comment: @Michael Harvey: Perhaps they liked his mind, though that never worked for me. I wonder if there's a recording of him squeaking. There's a photo of him studying when young where he looks quite handsome. He smelt of honey? Moonlighting at Gales, I expect. They all did it: E.M.Forster, Arnold Bennett...

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - I once heard a BBC recording from 1939 and I was a bit surprised that he didn't sound more 'Bromley', but he had been away from there and mixing upwards for decades by then. What have recently bothered me, as a lifelong (so far) Wells fan, are some of his prejudices. It has been said that if Wells wasn’t a professional anti-Semite he was certainly a talented amateur. Some say his statue in Woking should come down.

Comment: @Michael Harvey: I've never heard his voice but yes: he must've lost his 'Bromley' over the years. There are old recordings of Elgar with no noticeable Worcester. And perhaps people felt they should speak _posher_ when being recorded. I didn't know about the anti-semitism. Not sure about statues. Where (as they say) would it end? Maybe he was worse than TS Eliot, but as culpable as Rhodes? Tate? Eric Gill? G.B.Shaw was into eugenics...

Answer (score 1):

The sentence presumably means that the nice people had read many of the works of his prolific fellow author, H.G. Wells, and that their exposure to his remarkable ideas and stories had affected them accordingly.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._G._Wells